# Google's Bot Killing my Bandwidth

Tags: web, bandwidth, googlebot

I am facing strange and very serious problem with my website hosted accounts on hostgator reseller. since, march 23, 2018 my sites are being accessed by google's bot (userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 [compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html]). Their IP addresses are in range of 66.249.*.* and they change frequently. From my cPanel i can see as below;

66.249.79.79 /MzhmLzUxNzE5LzhmLzE2NjYvZmgz.asp 4/8/18, 5:30 AM 7377 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

66.249.79.75 /bXYtMzE2MS92b2svNzczODEtb2t3bw== 4/8/18, 5:29 AM 7377 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

66.249.79.75 /cTN1Lzc0ODQ3LzN1LzY0MzAvdXFi.asp 4/8/18, 5:29 AM 7377 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

66.249.79.75 /cGEwMGk2LzczODMvYTAvODU4MDEvMA== 4/8/18, 5:29 AM 7377 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

66.249.79.77 /eDItOTQ4NC8yYWIvMzMwNTctYWJtNA== 4/8/18, 5:29 AM 7377 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

66.249.79.79 /ZmlhLzc4NTk5L2lhLzMyNzcvYTVo.asp 4/8/18, 5:29 AM 7377 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

and there are tons of such. They are eating up my bandwidth and i am helpless from hostgator support team as they also don't have any specific solution to this.

Therefore, First i would like to know if there is any option or walkthrough to stop google temporarily to access my site? Secondly, can i do something to clear google's indexing urls list of my website?

Comment: https://snag.gy/79JrAM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Google will observe a crawl delay in seconds between requests that you can place in a robots.txt file in the root of your domain. See section called nonstandard extensions - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard.

You can also use Google's search console (formally called web master tools i think) to request urls be removed from their indexes and control other behaviour / see any issues indexing your site. You will need to register and then complete a verification process to link your account to your domain. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Comment: I have tried creating robots.txt and disallowing all agents. For the time being there i am still seeing visitors and google search console is also showing increased number of 404 errors. But this doesn't seems to be taking me to any solutions. 

Why google is trying to crawl random links on my website as it's already seeing 1000s of 404 errors in short interval of time.

Comment: I assume your / another site is creating broken links?

Comment: You could rewrite bogus urls to an empty file so they consume less bandwidth? That would reduce impact but not much you can do once Google has a list of urls to crawl.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now. I have created empty 404.php file so that there is 0 byte BW uses, but I am still seeing tons of bogus URL calls by google bot in my latest visitors section

Comment: Can you see where the backlinks originate? Webmaster tools has a backlinks report? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en

Comment: I had checked that also and there are no any such backlinks causing google bot to make request to my site